# Using send-to in MOSS document library

Tags: moss, document, sendto

I want to use the send-to option inside a MOSS document library to move the file to a folder in the same document library. If I select the url to the folder and then try the send-to option, it tells me the folder name is too long.

All the best

Answer (score 1):

The resulting URL to the new file cannot exceed 260 characters.